# Query a couchdb view on whether the key contains the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchdb

I am using a node couchdb api that does the following

```
couch.get(dbName, viewURL, {
          "key" : "Extra. This is what I want to search for. Extra."
    }).then(function(data, status, headers){
       if(data.data.rows[0] === undefined){
         // nothing exists in the view by this key
       }
       else console.log(data.data.rows[0]) // gives first JSON element in db

    });
```

My Question is if there is a way to query it so that the key only has to contain "This is what I want to search for." and doesnt care about the extra information. I realize that this is not the proper way that key:value pairs should be used, but I need it for a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use ElasticSearch for full-text search. But if you insist implementing it in CouchDB, you can try either of them:

1. Get all docs in your app and compare by your code (which like a dynamic view)
2. Try this plug-in for CouchDB: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene

Comment: Lucene is a plug-in that really helps!